# Python list to dictionary (regardless of length)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, matrix

I have a list which I want to be made in to a dictionary.

```
list_x = ['a', 'ada', 'aadsad', ......, 'sd']
```

Whatever that is in this list and however long (lets say 13 for now) to become a dictionary such that the second item of the list should be the key and everything else, including position 0 to be the values.

I have tried the dict() function from other examples, but it does not do what I want. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What would the resulting dictionary look like?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output you want?

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, now it is clear to me. Thank you all! I tested them as commented below. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this not work for you?

```
d = {}
d[list_x.pop(1)] = list_x
```

Comment: For Python 2.7+ there's also the dict comprehension: `{l.pop(1): l}`

Comment: @Blender, that's just a literal dict :P

Comment: yes but i cant use it in a loop, keeps replacing the dictionary with list_x

Comment: If you have a loop, put the `d = {}` outside the loop.

Comment: Holly Guacamole ! It worked! the d = {} was not in my loop but it was initialized another time before my print d

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to modify your `list`:

```
In [13]: list_x = ['a', 'ada', 'aadsad','sd']

In [14]: d={list_x[1]:list_x[0:1]+list_x[2:]}

In [15]: d
Out[15]: {'ada': ['a', 'aadsad', 'sd']}
```

EDIT:

if you're iterating over multiple lists:

```
In [72]: dic={}

In [73]: for x in multiple_lists:
   ....:     dic[x[1]]=x[0:1]+x[2:]
   ....:     
   ....:
```

Comment: this works also but not in a loop with many lists to make a dictionary out of all of them. keeps replacing d not append and i used it as d.append({list_x[1]:list_x[0:1]+list_x[2:]} and I was unsuccessful

Comment: @EisaMah you didn't mentioned that in your question that you've multiple lists, I've edited my answer see if it works now.

Comment: you are right, I am sorry. it wasn't clear to me that it made a difference. Python newbee here. But I tried it and totally works!! Superb!!! Thx so much!

Answer (score 1):

A strange requirement, but OK.

`dict_x = {list_x.pop(1): list_x}`

Comment: This works, but only for 1 iteration. So if I use this to feed many lists, it doesn't add to dict_x it keeps replacing it :(

Comment: worked! it didn't work because i was initializing it wrong!! thnx!

Answer (score 1):

And the other method without slicing that hasn't been mentioned:

```
dict.fromkeys( (list_x.pop(1),), list_x)
```

Answer (score 1):

And now an answer that *doesn't* mutate the original list and doesn't add slices:

```
>>> r = range(len(list_x))
>>> del r[1]
>>> {list_x[1]: operator.itemgetter(*r)(list_x)}
{'ada': ('a', 'aadsad', ......, 'sd')}
```

Comment: roughly equivalent to `{list_x[1]: [k for i, k in enumerate(list_x) if i != 1]}`

Comment: Hi, but do i need to import something to make the operator function work? it doesn't like it :(

Comment: Thx, but what is it? I searched google for python operator and python operator.itemgetter and there is a lot of explanation but I dont see import operator ... is this it?

Comment: This worked too, but dict_x = {list_x.pop(1): list_x} is shorter and works!! Thx so much Ignacio for your help on this and the other matrix :)

Answer (score 1):

without mutating the original

```
tmp = list_x[:]
{tmp.pop(1): tmp}
```